# how to share a single resource (tablet) from multiple windows machines

Tags: networking, usb, port-forwarding

I want to share single Android table from multiple development systems.

the scenario is that I and my colleague share a same tablet for android development purposes.
so, each time anyone has to test his app, he has to take out the usb and connect to his development machine.

this thing must be possible that  I deploy my app in that tablet using network. don't know how.
any help or suggestions appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to directly share the Android itself might be something or a pain, but you could try leaving the Android attached to a computer running an SSH server, or remote desktop software if you need the GUI, or whatever you'd need in the way of resources (maybe a VM host server would do; something running headless virtualbox).

Depending on the nature of the software you're writing, you might need to coordinate what times various tests are being run against the tablet, but since that would be an issue, anyway, this solution isn't sacrificing all that much. On the other hand, if you know an easy way to hook the Android tablet up to the internet directly, naturally you can have it run the SSH server, or the remote desktop software.

And, you probably already did this so I apologize if it is insulting to mention, but you may also want to look into Android emulation.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

If you all just need to be working with the same code, and not necessarily the same physical machine, you might not need an actual machine most of the time, so the issue of sharing it might not be a significant issue.

Comment: we r working on a sort of game, so real-time testing is necessary.